# Why does OpenEdge ODBC connection fail with error 126 in IIS but on in VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, iis, odbc, progress-4gl, openedge

I have an ASP.net web service application that connects to a Progress OpenEdge 10.1B database via ODBC.  My development machine is XP Pro and runs everything fine.  I am now moving the application into a test environment.  The test machine is also XP Pro.  It matches the dev machine except for that the Progress Server is not running locally.  I am able to run the project out of VS2010 and the web service makes the ODBC connection and returns the data without error.  When I deploy the application to IIS (which is running locally) the ODBC connection fails with this error:

**System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: ERROR [IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  126 (OpenEdge 10.1B driver).
**

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Progress Knowledgebase at http://progress.atgnow.com/esprogress/Group.jsp?bgroup=progress

This entry seems potentially relevant:

ID: P36468
Title: "ASP page fails to launch due to the error 126 when loading the ODBC driver"
Created: 08/11/2003     Last Modified: 10/14/2008
Status: Verified

Symptoms:
ASP page fails to launch due to the error 126 when loading the ODBC driver
Specified driver could not be loaded due to system "error 126" (MERANT 3.70 32-BIT PROGRESS)
Testing the connection from ODBC Data Administration works fine
Using IIS built in account for the IIS and ASP.

Facts:
Windows NT 32 Intel/Windows 2000
Progress 9.1x
IIS

Cause:
IIS built-in account (IUSR_machine_name) does not have permissions to access network
resources which will be the case if Progress has been installed on the network shared drive.

Fixes:
Install Progress on the local drive to the IIS and add the read and execute
permission for the IUSR account to all the files in the installation directory.

Comment: That seems to be the only thing that is making sense write now.  Unfortunately I cannot install progress on the test dev machine.